# "Request For Permission" Popup window in Facebook C# SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 app, using Canvas Attribute.

I am asking for this permission only "user_about_me".

The "Request for Permission" window is not popping up. I am automatically logged in to Facebook without any "Allow" "Don't Allow".

Note that I am not using JSDK.

Thanks

Comment: How are you asking for the permission? Are you using the CanvasAuthorize attribute on your controller?

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook C# SDK doesn't have any functionality for opening a permission dialog. You must use the Facebook Javascript SDK for this.